# How to avoid sendgrid overriding my classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I just added Sendgrid to my app using the

```
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
```

So I start to have problems with my class loading. The issue is, I already have a model called client.rb

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
```

So, sometimes the CanCanCan or other methods, are being overrided by the Sendgrid client class. For instance here:

```
if user.talent.present?
  # Talents can only read his own booking model
  can [:read, :accept, :check_in, :update], Booking, { talent: { user_id: user.id } }

  # Talents can only see his own connections
  can :read, Connection, Connection.where('user_1_id = :id or user_2_id  = :id', id: user.id) do |connection|
    (connection.user_1_id == user.id) || (connection.user_2_id == user.id)
  end

  can :create, Photo
  # can :read, Photo, user_id: user.id
  can :update, Photo, user_id: user.id
  can :delete, Photo, user_id: user.id

elsif user.client.present?
  can :create, Booking
  can [:read, :update], Booking, user_id: user.id
  #can :update, Booking, { talent: { user_id: user.id } }
  # Should we able to delete Bookings? or those created bookings get archive?

  # TODO: Really?
  # can :read, Agency
  # can :update, Client, user_id: user.id
```

In this method user.client.present? breaks the app, because CanCanCan thinks that Client is a instance of Sendgrid::Client not my own model

How can I make my app knows all the time that "client" should be my own class, not the Sendgrid one?

The only points Im importing sendgrid are on my mailers:

```
require 'sendgrid-ruby'
include SendGrid

class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> include SendGrid
> ```

Yeah, that's where your problem is. Don't do this.

In your defense, this line *does* exist in [SendGrid's quick start snippets](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby#quick-start), but I'm not sure what for. Looks unused. Every usage of sendgrid's classes is namespaced. So yes, just remove it and you should be good.

Have a look at this too: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/rubyonrails/

Comment: sendgrid-ruby's [`TROUBLESHOOTING.md` mentions this](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#rails-specifics), but it's beyond me why they advise `include SendGrid` at all.